# Can we identify that who downloaded our application from playstore

Tags: android, google-play

Can we identify that who downloaded our application from playstore? I am checking into my developer console there is no option provided i think. Also can we check that if a user has downloaded our app multiple times from play store through our developer console ?

Comment: DOn't think you can figure out who downloaded the app.

Comment: as far as I know nop you cannot , however in server side there is something you can do about it , you can identify the ip and check how may time is loging into the session

Comment: Manish yes we can figure out from our app and our servers but I clearly asked about if there is any option in developer console

Answer (score 0):

I've checked on my own dev console and I don't believe there is one built in. 
There is no real way unless you ask the user to register their information for the app. Also, I believe it would be a privacy issue and a hassle with Google if they kept track all the downloading information for each of its users.

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to know who specifically downloading your app? Shouldn't number be enough to hint you of your apps popularity?